# Compile test program with wxWidgets in MAC

Tags: macos, wxwidgets

OS: MAC X 10.7.0

The Mac OS X install an older version of wxMac(wxMac-2.8.8.1) in /usr, but I install a newer one(wxMac-2.8.12.0) in /usr/local. To install it, I compile the new one with the flag:

arch_flags="-arch i386"
./configure CFLAGS="$arch_flags" CXXFLAGS="$arch_flags" CPPFLAGS="$arch_flags" LDFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCXXFLAGS="$arch_flags" --enable-unicode --enable-debug --disable-shared

Then I write a simple program(hello2.cpp) to test it:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

class HelloWorldApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
private:
    wxButton *button;
};


IMPLEMENT_APP(HelloWorldApp)

bool HelloWorldApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame((wxFrame*) NULL, -1, _T("Hello wxWidgets World"));
    frame->CreateStatusBar();
    frame->SetStatusText(_T("Hello World"));
    button = new wxButton((wxFrame *)frame, -2, _T("123"));
    frame->Show(TRUE);
    SetTopWindow(frame);

    return true;
}
```

I compile this test program in the command line with the flag:

g++ hello2.cpp `/usr/local/bin/wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o hello2

But I receive some warnings and errors. I am a newbie in Mac programming, so I don't know the reason. I just have to say: help!

Here is the result of compiling:

ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      wxMBConv_iconv::GetMBNulLen() const  in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::WC2MB(char*, wchar_t const*, unsigned long) constin libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::WC2MB(char*, wchar_t const*, unsigned long) constin libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::MB2WC(wchar_t*, char const*, unsigned long) constin libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::MB2WC(wchar_t*, char const*, unsigned long) constin libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::wxMBConv_iconv(wchar_t const*)in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
      wxMBConv_iconv::~wxMBConv_iconv()in libwx_base_carbonud-2.8.a(baselib_strconv.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall wxMac-2.8.12.
I installl wxWidgets-2.9.2(./configure --enable-unicode --enable-debug --disable-shared)

I compile the test program with g++ hello2.cpp `/usr/local/bin/wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o hello2 again. There only one warning:

ld: warning: in /System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

I think that's OK.